# MongoDB query to push entry from one collection into another

Tags: mongodb

Collection 1:

```
nodeDB : [{
           "VARIANTS": [
            {"NAME" : Brand},
            {"NAME" : Price},
            {"NAME" : Colour},
            {"NAME" : Size}
           ]
           }]
```

A form is generated from VARIANTS.The values of this form are to be pushed into New DB called ProductDB
Collection2:

```
ProductDB [{
            {"Brand" : Lee},
            {"Price" : 100},
            {"Color" : Red},
            {"Size"  : M}
         }]
```

The values are taken from the user interface.

**EDIT**

JS File:

```
Template.dpVar.variant=nodeDB.find({}, { "VARIENTS.NAME": 1, _id : 0 } );

   // Wait for a 'submit'
      Template.inputDB.events = {
        'submit' : function (e, tmpl) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var NAME= {
            NAME: tmpl.find("#NAME").value
          }; 
   nodeDB.insert(template_name);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like requirements with no attempt to do anything by OP

Comment: I have attempted the code and shared it as asked.I purposefully skipped it because that part is working and will not serve any purpose for the reader

Comment: you tagged this as monogodb, which suggests that it should be done in a shell. The code that you posted, has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: I need mongoquery to be used in JS file if possible, otherwise if someone helps me with MongoDB shell also, I can convert it into JS file

Comment: db.nodes.find({"ACTIVE" : 1, "VARIENTS.ACCESS" : "PUBLIC" }, { "VARIENTS.NAME": 1,"VARIENTS.DATATYPE":1, _id : 0 } ).pretty()

Comment: This was the mongoDb query I was using in mongo Shell.But it is of no use to the reader, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using meteor JS.
You need to perform action onclick of submit button,

```
<table id="TemplateCreateNewStructure" class=" table table-withborder table-type1">

</table>
```

Then call ajax and display your data in table then click on submit button, insert your record in new collection like tis way

```
function createPreviewFormForTemplate(opt){
  if VARIANTS.name == 'Brand'
      tr = tr='<tr><td>'+VARIANTS.name+'</td><td <input id="dtBoxIN" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="ENter Brand"/> <div id="dtBox"></div></td></tr>';    
$("#TemplateCreateNewStructure").append(tr);
```

Once you done with all condition then save tables data into a object and that object you need to insert into another collection 
you can get your value by using trim method

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    data = {
     "brand": $("#dtBoxIN").val().trim(),
};
```

you need to send this data object to your backend code 
at the backend code you need to run this command

```
db.collection.insert(data)
```